# Misdirected Bitcoin?

Tags: transactions

Good day. I bought 2 Bitcoin from a reputable dealer and asked that they be transferred them to my private Electrum Standard Wallet. The Bitcoin has not arrived in my wallet. The dealer has confirmed sending the Bitcoin to the correct address. The "History" tab of the wallet shows a new line with an exclamation mark inside a triangle with the word "Replaceable" next to it and +0 under the Amount. Is it possible that the Bitcoin has been lost or misdirected? Have I done something wrong with the wallet that must be changed? I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: there are not many details like tx number or addresses... so an Electrum wallet showing the tx looks primarily ok. Maybe it takes some time until tx gets confirmed. See if you find the tx number, or ask the service provider (aka dealer) to give you the tx number. Then you can take your address or your tx number and verify on "blockchain.info" the status. Let us know what you see, and we might find a proper answer.

Comment: I have checked on blockchain.info using the address and it indicates that the Bitcoin was delivered. My wallet however shows zero change to the balance. Apart from the History tab which shows the triangle and the word “replaceable” with a zero balance received.  The Receive tab shows the transaction request. It also shows something that may reflect a problem. When the request for a new receiving address is made on this wallet, a box provides the request to expire within 1 Hour, 1 Day, 1 week and Never. 

The “Never” option was chosen . Was it a mistake to use the “Never” option perhaps?

Comment: When blockchain.info shows the tx wih the funds of your address (with several confirmations), then you „have“ the funds. This is ok, and your provider obviously sent the funds. Now s.th. in your wallet seems not ok. Have you access to your private key? Or to the initial seed? Then I would create on a different system a restore of the wallet, or use a different wallet and load the private key into it. From there you could spend the funds.